# SQL71516 error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

```
CREATE TABLE ChannelList 
(
    [ch_id] INT NOT NULL,
    [ch_name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [ch_production] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [ch_genre] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ch_rating] INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ch_id]) 
)

CREATE TABLE Seasons 
(
    [ss_name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [ss_id] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ss_noep] INT NULL, 
    [ss_startdate] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [ss_enddate] DATE NULL, 
    [ss_studio] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ss_rating] INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ss_id])
)

CREATE TABLE actor 
(
    [ac_name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [ac_id] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ac_age] INT NULL, 
    [ac_sex] VARCHAR(3) NULL, 
    [ac_season] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ac_id]) 
)

CREATE TABLE StudioList 
(
    [st_name] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [st_address] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [st_owner] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [st_website] NCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([st_website]) 
)

CREATE TABLE EpisodeList 
(
    [ep_chid] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ep_chname] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ep_id] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [ep_name] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ep_seasonid] INT NULL, 
    [ep_genre] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ep_rating] INT NULL, 
    [ep_airdate] DATE NULL, 
    [ep_actor] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    [ep_studio] VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ep_id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EpisodeList_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY (ep_chid) REFERENCES ChannelList([ch_id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EpisodeList_ToTable_1] FOREIGN KEY (ep_chname) REFERENCES ChannelList(ch_name), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EpisodeList_ToTable_2] FOREIGN KEY (ep_seasonid) REFERENCES Seasons(ss_id), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EpisodeList_ToTable_3] FOREIGN KEY (ep_actor) REFERENCES actor(ac_name), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EpisodeList_ToTable_4] FOREIGN KEY (ep_studio) REFERENCES StudioList(st_name) 
)
```

I am getting the same error multiple times - can someone please help?

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[ChannelList]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[actor]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[StudioList]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Comment: The error message is actually pretty clear. When creating the `EpisodeList` table, you are referencing the column `ch_name` of the `ChannelList` table, which is not the primary key of that table

Comment: A foreign key can **only** reference the **primary key** of the referenced table (or in SQL Server also a column / set of columns that is (are) part of a **unique constraint** or unique index - this is **not** the case for `actor.ac_name` or `studiolist.st_name`)